# Add or edit the master template of a Google Drive presentation

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using the `googleapis` Node module.

I can create a new presentation using `slides.presentations.create` and edit the content using `slides.presentations.batchUpdate`, but I don't know how to add a master to the deck with a bunch of layouts.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I swear we have already seen this question today.   Did you check the documentation?  https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest

Comment: I've poured through the docs in excruciating detail over the last week. Can you point me to the relevant part at all? Or a function name or something that I can search for? There's nothing obvious in there from what I can see. Thanks! (Also, yes, I posted before but decided to simplify my question, appreciate you taking the time to respond)

Comment: On this link, for instance, I can't seem to find any batchUpdate request type for creating or modifying the master or any layouts. https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#Request and I see that in the documentation for `presentations.create` that all data except `title` and `presentationId` are ignored.

Comment: I can point out the fact that documentation is there to document what is supported not what is not supported.  have you considered submitting a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191598%2B)?

Comment: Ah, ok so you are suggesting that this isn't possible today? I'll submit a feature request, thank you.